# Stacking words with fixed spacing between them

Tags: spacing, macros

I've created a couple of little macros that enable me to stack words on top of each other.    It's very crude but works well.    However the spacing between the words varies depending on the words.   I'd like to be able to have control over the gap between the two rows, so they all the same.

My macros are

```
\def\lksStack#1#2#3{\ensuremath{\mathop{\empty}_{\text{#3#2}}^{\text{#3 #1}}} } 
   \def\rsmlStack#1#2{\lksStack{#1}{#2}{\rm \small}}
```

This text

```
there is in a $\rsmlStack{{\sf con}}{{\sf pro}}$ game, 
an $\rsmlStack{upper}{lower}$
but no $\rsmlStack{lower}{upper}$ bound on the right-hand side of
```

produces this ugly uneven output

[image]

Could somebody suggest a way of getting consistent spacing?   Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can increase the default line spacing with the `setspace` package, so that lines containing no stacks are spaced the same as lines containing stacked words.  Also, I show how to use the `stackengine` package to accomplish the stack.  To assure that the spacing within the stack is consistent, regardless of letter descenders, etc., one must use a so-called long stack that regulates the baselineskip of the stack, rather than the vertical gap between words.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,setspace}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\parskip 1em
\spacing{1.5}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{10pt}
\begin{document}
\def\mytext{If you walk \stackanchor{left}{right}, you will see a
\stackanchor{house}{boat} with \stackanchor{an old man}{a cat}.}

\lipsum[1]\mytext\lipsum[2]\mytext\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

The line spacing can be tghtened by making a macro, here `\mystack`, that sets the text in a smaller size with a tighter baselineskip:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,setspace}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\parskip 1em
\spacing{1.3}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{7pt}
\newcommand\mystack[2]{\stackanchor{\footnotesize#1}{\footnotesize#2}}
\begin{document}
\def\mytext{If you walk \mystack{left}{right}, you will see a
\mystack{house}{boat} with \mystack{an old man}{a cat}.}

\lipsum[1]\mytext\lipsum[2]\mytext\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Is there a way to make the stacked words slightly smaller, say, `\small` or `\footnotesize`? (The OP seems to use `\small`.)

Comment: @Mico See addendum.

Comment: I like this setting much better than my clumsy one.     I wanted a bit of flexibility with the spacing, so I constructed:`\def\lksStack#1#2#3#4{\setstackgap{L}{#4 pt}\stackanchor{#3 #1}{#3 #2}}`
`\newcommand{\ismlStack}[3][10]{\lksStack{#2}{#3}{\itshape \small}{#1}}`
`\newcommand{\rsmlStack}[3][10]{\lksStack{#2}{#3}{\rmfamily \small}{#1}}` so I could modify the 10pt spacing if necessary.

Comment: @LeoSimon I am glad the solution proved versatile for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You could add `\mathstrut` directives to the two arguments of `\rsmlStack`:

```
\def\rsmlStack#1#2{\lksStack{#1\mathstrut}{#2\mathstrut}{\rmfamily\small}}
```

Note that `\rm` and `\sf` are considered deprecated under LaTeX2e; in fact, they will not work at all in several important document classes. Use `\rmfamily` and `\sffamily` instead. In the code shown below, I also suggest using `\footnotesize` instead of `\small` for the stacked material. To go even smaller, use `\scriptsize`.

[image]

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\text' and '\ensuremath' macros
\def\lksStack#1#2#3{\ensuremath{{}_{\text{#3#2}}^{\text{#3#1}}} } 
\def\rsmlStack#1#2{\lksStack{#1\mathstrut}{#2\mathstrut}{\rmfamily\footnotesize}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
there is in a 
$\rsmlStack{\textsf{con}}{\textsf{pro}}$ game, 
an $\rsmlStack{upper}{lower}$
but no $\rsmlStack{lower}{upper}$ bound on the right-hand side of
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works nicely, thanks but I prefer the simpler `stackengine` approach.